# how to handle redirection url in port forwarding - docker container

Tags: magento, redirect, docker, docker-container

I build **magento application** in docker container, I am trying to access that container from remote machine using `docker port forwarding`.

### System A

**create container :** `docker run -it -d -p 8000:80 -h tm.gworks.mobi -v /var/www/public --privileged --name testmachineone magedev`

**container ip :** `172.17.0.2`

**System A ip :** `192.168.1.6`

I can able to access webserver using both ip in **system A** `http://172.17.0.2` && `http://192.168.1.6:8000`

**note:** if I access `http://192.168.1.6:8000` it will get automatically redirect to `http://172.17.0.2` that is default behavior of magento.

### System B

if I access `http://192.168.1.6:8000` it will get automatically redirect to `http://172.17.0.2` but **system B** can't able to access `http://172.17.0.2` so it throws 404 error.

as per my search we can't access docker container ip from remote host, only way is port forwarding. But I stuck with URL redirection in port forwarding.

how to sort out this issues?

Comment: system B doesn't need to have access to 172.17.0.2. By specifying `-p 8000:80` your internal container (at address 172.17.0.2) will be accessible through the host A at address 192.168.1.6:8000. From Host B's point of view, it will look as if your container (magento) is running at ip 192.168.1.6

Comment: when I access `192.168.1.6:8000` in system B, it redirects to `172.17.0.2` so system B throws 404 error. I can't stop redirection because it is a default behaviour of magento. feel free to mention in comment, if you need further clarity. I will update :-)

Comment: That's a magento config issue then. There's probably some option to specify the host ip to magento on startup.

Comment: I raised this question for the purpose of how to generally handle redirection in port forwarding like above scenario.

Comment: You already handle port forwarding correctly as per your code above. There's nothing to correct in your code above. The problem is probably a magento config issue as I said.